# How to know if a method or object from cpp is supported in cython?

Tags: c++, cython

How to know if a method or object from cpp is supported in cython?
For example I am searching if make_move_iterator exist but could not find any information about it.

if it is not supported, is there a way to copy its implementation and use it in a cdef extern?

Comment: I suppose you can wrap the class if it's not available and use them in cython, you may refer to the documentation >> https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you're referring from the `from libcpp cimport ...` files that Cython provides that wrap the C++ standard library?

The easiest thing is probably just to use GitHub search on the Cython GitHub repository and see if the function is there (although make sure the function you're using is in the release you're using). They're all [pxd files under Cython/Includes/libcpp](https://github.com/cython/cython/tree/master/Cython/Includes/libcpp).

These wrapper contain no internal magic and don't do anything you can't write yourself with `cdef extern from`. Therefore if something isn't there you should be able to write a definition for it yourself. Follow the wrappers that do exist for guidance. Occasionally you hit limitations of Cython's understanding of c++ though which can make things difficult to wrap.